# Simple grid draw doesn't work

Tags: grid, draw

I'm trying to draw a simple grid on a canvas. First I did this

```
function start()
{   
   var x = 0;
   var y = 0;

    for (x = 0; x < 500; x += 50)
    {
        line(0 + x, 50 + y, 50 + x, 50 + y, 1, "#111");
        line(50 + x, 0 + y, 50 + x, 50 + y, 1, "#111");

        if (x == 450)
        {
            x = -50;
            y += 50;
        }
        if (y == 500)
        {
            x = 500;
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine. But I want to be able to easily change the size of the grid and canvas. So I did this:

```
function start()
{   
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var cW = canvas.width;
    var cH = canvas.hight;
    var gS = 50; //gS = gridSpace

    for (x = 0; x < cW; x += gS)
    {
        line(0 + x, gS + y, gS + x, gS + y, 1, "#111");
        line(gS + x, 0 + y, gS + x, gS + y, 1, "#111");

        if (x == cW - gS)
        {
            x = -gS;
            y += gS;
        }
        if (y == cH)
        {
            x = cW;
        }
    }
}
```

It does not work! Please help me.

PS. I'm using a library.
`

Comment: Please be more specific. What language, what framework, what library, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to approach this a little differently. I'm not entirely sure of what you're trying to accomplish here, but here are some pointers/questions that may guide you toward what you're trying to do:

- When drawing a grid, you are drawing a series of horizontal lines and a series of vertical lines. Use two loops to simplify that process.
- For the horizontal lines, the y-value varies, but the x-coords for the line endpoints stay the same (e.g. 0 and cW). The converse applies to the vertical lines.
- What kind of spacing are you really trying to achieve? Typically you're looking at either dividing the space into a certain number of areas (say 6 rows and 4 columns), or spacing that doesn't adapt to the specific canvas you're drawing on (this is what you're code seems to be trying to do). So, the first will adapt to the size of the canvas while the latter will just display more/fewer rows/columns as the canvas size varies.

I hope that helps you solve your problem, please let me know if you need any more help!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, is that you have `height` spelled incorrectly. I believe javascript, if this is javascript, won't complain about incorrectly named variables. (I could be wrong on that).

```
var cH = canvas.hight;
```

should be

```
var cH = canvas.height;
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I noticed that myself after a while. It's fixed now thanks!